# Function RTRIM/LTRIM invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s)

Tags: hibernate, sybase, hibernate-mapping

Error on RTRIM/LTRIM in HQL on TEXT datatype Sybase Database table column. I have also tried removing `sql-type="text"`.

Please find below my coding details:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <property name="prop1" type="text">
            <column name="col1" sql-type="text"/>
  </property>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

HQL:

```
String queryTest= "SELECT * FROM TestTb WHERE id="+Long.parseLong(rowID) + " and (prop1 is not null) and (ltrim(prop1) <> '') and (rtrim(prop1) <> '') ";
```

Error on query execution:

```
WARN  (org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter)  - SQL Error: 11021, SQLState: ZZZZZ
ERROR (org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter)  - Function LTRIM invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).
ERROR (org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:101)  - Function LTRIM invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).
WARN  (org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter)  - SQL Error: 11021, SQLState: ZZZZZ
ERROR (org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter)  - Function RTRIM invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please check if the same query works properly in plan SQL - for example in a client like isql or squirrelsql. I don't think that this issue is related to hibernate.